# what is the correct way to change the color of a circle in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx

The fill color of my circle is changing, but not appearing as the changed color on the screen. The screen updates every 125 milliseconds with the code below:

```
// refresh screen periodically
public void updateScreen(QTree qt, double n) {
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(n), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        
        
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
            
            /* Run this code every n milliseconds */
            
            qGroup.getChildren().clear();
            pGroup.getChildren().clear();
            uGroup.getChildren().clear();
            
            box.show(uGroup);
            
            // first I change all circles to default color
            for(Point p : points) {
                p.setColor(Color.CADETBLUE);
            }
            
            // then change specific points to lime
            ArrayList<Point> found = qt.query(box);
            for(int i = 0; i < found.size(); i++) { 
                found.get(i).setColor(Color.LIMEGREEN);
                // I use this to find out if the
                // color is actually changing
                System.out.println(found.get(i).cir);
            }
            
            // then display the points
            for(Point p : points) {
                p.show(pGroup); // display a point
            }
            
            qt.show(qGroup); // display quad tree
            
            /**************************************/
            
        }
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
}
```

The point class that I made is this

```
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class Point {
    public double x, y;
    public Circle cir;
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    
        cir = new Circle(this.x, this.y, 4);
    }

    public void show(Group g) {
        g.getChildren().add(cir);
    }

    public void setColor(Color c) {
        cir.setFill(c);
    }

    public void setRadius(double r) {
        cir.setRadius(r);
    }
}
```

when I run the code my print statement writes

Circle[centerX=408.1527831669267, centerY=357.17624700724684, radius=4.0, fill=0x32cd32ff]

the color is changing to 32cd32ff which is lime green but doesn't update to the color on the screen.

[Picture of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlo3l.png)

the points within the box are supposed to turn lime green, but instead, it stays cadet blue.

I might be missing something painfully obvious, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I know I could do it without the timeline, but I am planning on moving the box with my mouse later. Am I missing something?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: How often do you call `updateScreen`?

Comment: Just once in the setup

Answer (score 0):

if you refresh your screen every 125 ms .. and the code start with other color and u change then it's refresh to old color and change so you won't see the new color

Comment: maybe if u put the first color out side refreshing your problem will be solved

Comment: I put the first color outside the timeline, but the problem still persists. For some reason, the colors won't change.